# Ruby output of reading into a textfile

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble with the output of my code.
I added the out, in, re-out to see what was happenning...
I tried to add if line.length != 0 and line != 0, to not print empty lines,
but it doesn't work.. 
Here is the output:

```
Going to open 'TextFile.rtf'
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in
66666666
re-out
out
in
99999999
re-out
out
in

re-out
out
in
25252525
re-out
out
in
11111111
re-out
```

My textfile:

```
BABA66666666 Hd12 
HEAD99999999 HDAS   
HEAD25252525  A1234  
SSSS11111111 No12
```

My code:

```
def HID_num(str)
    matchtemp = ""
    temp = str.split(" ")
    temp.map! do |element|
        matches = element.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
        next unless matches
        matchtemp = matches[1]
    end.compact
    puts matchtemp
end

if ARGV.length != 1
    puts "We need exactly one parameter. The name of a file."
    exit;
end

filename = ARGV[0]
puts "Going to open '#{filename}'"

fh = open filename

while (line = fh.gets)
    puts "out"
    if(line.length != 0)
        puts "in"
     HID_num(line)
    end
    puts "re-out"
end

fh.close
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What output are you **expecting**? I don't know what your question is.

Comment: Like it checks if the IDs are correct: 4 uppercases letters, 8 digits after. It should return only the 8 digits valid

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure that your code precisely, unambiguously, efficiently, and reproducably demonstrates the problem, and that it is the minimal amount of code required to do so, IOW a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method is a bit of a mess:

```
def HID_num(str)
  matchtemp = ""
  temp = str.split(" ")
  temp.map! do |element|
    matches = element.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
    next unless matches
    matchtemp = matches[1]
  end.compact
  puts matchtemp
end
```

Since you only want to *print* the matches, there's no need to use `map` or `compact` here. You can just do this:

```
def HID_num(str)
  str.split(" ").each do |element|
    matches = element.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
    puts matches[1] if matches
  end
end
```

Your original version wasn't working as expected because you were still printing the empty string (`matchtemp = ""`), even when no match was found.